# Flutter get Images by extension form storage

Tags: android, regex, flutter, dart, iso

I want to know how can I compare file extension

```
void main() {
  List<String> image = ["sdasd/dsd.png","sdafd/ddd.jpeg","sdsdd/dgd.gif","sdasd/dhd.png","sdasd/dhd.txt",];

  final RegExp regExp =
      RegExp(".(gif|jpe?g|tiff?|png|webp|bmp)", caseSensitive: true);

  for (var img in image) {
    print(img.contains(regExp));
  }
}
```

**Output:**
true
true
true
true
false

**Problem**

If I put ".pngk" it shows me "true",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is looking for matches in the entire string, not at the end.

Add `$` to end:

```
".(gif|jpe?g|tiff?|png|webp|bmp)\$"
```

`$` matches position just after the last character of the string.

Comment: Expected an identifier. get Error

Comment: Sorry, forgot escape character. Use \$

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  List<String> image = [
    "d1.Png",
    "d2.jpeg",
    "d3.gif",
    "d4.png",
    "d5.txt",
  ];
  List? newImages = [];

  final RegExp regExp =
      RegExp(".(gif|jpe?g|tiff?|png|webp|bmp)\$", caseSensitive: false);

  for (var img in image) {
    if (img.contains(regExp)) {
      newImages.add(img);
      print(img);
    }
  }

  if (newImages != null) {
    print("${newImages.length}");
  }
}
```